# Rolling Average in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate the rolling average for over three periods.

For instance,
Seq 3, it is calculated as (0.59 + 0.69 + 0.37) /3
Seq 4, it is calculated as (0.69 +0.37+ 1.05)/3
and so on

[image]

Using a sequence number because need to calculate by periods rather than days or months.

My DAX Query is this -

Rolling Average =

[image]

It does not seem to be working. The Rolling average is wrong. Can someone help with this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work like this:

```
Rolling Average =      
var maxSEQ = MAX('Average Toil'[SEQ]) 
var sumSEQ = CALCULATE(SUM('Average Toil'[Average Toil Accrued]),
         ALL('Average Toil'), 'Average Toil'[SEQ] <= maxSEQ &&
        'Average Toil'[SEQ] >= maxSEQ-2) 
var ravg = DIVIDE(sumSEQ, 3) 
return 
IF(maxSEQ > 2, ravg)
```

Edit: On a second thought, off course it should also work with ALLSELECTED, in case there is something you dont want to show up:

```
Rolling Average =      
var maxSEQ = MAX('Average Toil'[SEQ]) 
var sumSEQ = CALCULATE(SUM('Average Toil'[Average Toil Accrued]),
         ALLSELECTED('Average Toil'), 'Average Toil'[SEQ] <= maxSEQ &&
        'Average Toil'[SEQ] >= maxSEQ-2) 
var ravg = DIVIDE(sumSEQ, 3) 
return 
IF(maxSEQ > 2, ravg)
```

Comment: The second solution works. Thank you so much!